# Angular 2 ngFor not rendering

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to use `ngFor` under a template and retrieve children to modify them later.

Here is my template:

```
<div (mouseenter)="showTooltip()" (mouseleave)="hideTooltip()" (mousedown)='onMouseDown($event)' class='slider slider-{{ orientation }}'>
      <div class='slider-track'>
        <div #trackLow class='slider-track-low' [ngClass]="{hide: (type === 'slider' || selection === 'none' || selection === 'after')}"></div>
        <div #trackSelection class='slider-selection' [ngClass]="{hide: (selection === 'none')}"></div>
        <div #trackHigh class='slider-track-high' [ngClass]="{hide: (selection === 'none' || selection === 'before')}"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="slider-tick-label-container" [ngClass]="{hide: labels.length === 0}">
        <div #labelElements *ngFor="let label of ticksLabels" class="slider-tick-label">{{ label }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-tick-container" [ngClass]="{hide: ticks.length === 0}">
        <div #tickElements *ngFor="let tick of ticks" class="slider-tick {{ handleType }}">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div #tooltipMain class="tooltip tooltip-main {{ tooltipPosition }}" role="presentation">
        <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
        <div #tooltipMainInner class="tooltip-inner">Current value: {{ value }}</div>
      </div>
      <div #tooltipMin class="tooltip tooltip-min {{ tooltipPosition }}" role="presentation">
        <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
        <div #tooltipMinInner class="tooltip-inner"></div>
      </div>
      <div #tooltipMax class="tooltip tooltip-max {{ tooltipPosition }}" role="presentation">
        <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
        <div #tooltipMaxInner class="tooltip-inner"></div>
      </div>
      <div #minHandle tabindex="0" (keydown)="keydown(0, $event)" (focus)="showTooltip()" (blur)="hideTooltip()" class='slider-handle min-slider-handle {{ handleType }}' role='slider'></div>
      <div #maxHandle tabindex="0" (keydown)="keydown(1, $event)" (focus)="showTooltip()" (blur)="hideTooltip()" class='slider-handle max-slider-handle {{ handleType }}' [ngClass]="{hide: type === 'slider'}" role='slider'></div>
</div>
```

Both `ngFor` are rended like this in DOM:

```
<div class="slider-tick-container">
    <!--template bindings={}-->
</div>
```

In my component I try to retrieve elements with:

```
@ViewChildren('tickElements') private tickElements: QueryList<ElementRef>;
@ViewChildren('labelElements') private labelElements: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Both are undefined because of the rendering problem...

I try to remove the template and replace it by `<div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]">{{i}}</div>` and same problem !

The full code is available here: https://github.com/jaumard/ng2-bootstrap/blob/ticksLabels/components/slider/slider.component.ts#L15

Comment: as i can see in your code you are using `@Input() public ticksPositions: Array<number> = [0, 30, 100];
@Input() public ticksLabels: Array<string> = ['one', 'two', 'tree'];` why are u using `@input` here if you har coding the values use `@input ` if you are going to pass the values from parent components. Removing `@input ` will make the code work fine i guess.

Comment: Because at first I was thinking the @input cause the problem so I remove them and hardcode the data, but same problem.
I also try a simple <div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">{{i}} </div> but same problem...

Comment: ok the problem was the ngClass just above witch reference an undefined property... After correction all is working great